# Can't query GeoPackage geometry via SQLite client

Tags: spatialite, geopackage, sqlite

I have a GeoPackage and I want to select the geometry as text from the SQLite command-line client. Here's what I've done:

1. Run `sqlite3`
2. Load SpatiaLite with `.load /path/to/mod_spatialite.dylib` (I'm on a Mac)
3. Run the following query:

```
sqlite> select astext(geom) from boundary;
```

There aren't any errors, but the client prints a blank newline as the result.

Am I doing something wrong, or can anyone think of other diagnostics?

I'm new to SpatiaLite/GeoPackage.

The layer loads fine in QGIS! The geometry looks fine. It's one big multipolygon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Geometries in SpatiaLite are not encoded in the same way than geometries in GeoPackage. The AsText/ST_AsText function needs a SpatiaLite geometry as an input. The function returns NULL for GeoPackage geometries because it does not understand what they are.

However, SpatiaLite has a function "CastAutomagic" that converts GeoPackage geometries into SpatiaLite geometries. Add the function into your query and it will handle the GeoPackage geometries.

```
SELECT AsText(CastAutomagic(geom)) from boundary;
```

See the manual of the SpatiaLite functions https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html.

> **CastAutomagic**
>
> This function will indifferently accept on input:
>
> - a SpatiaLite own BLOB Geometry
> - a GPKG own BLOB Geometry
>
> then returning a SpatiaLite own BLOB geometry.

Answer (score 0):

When connecting to a GeoPackage file, in addition to loading the `mod_spatialite` sqlite extension an additional initialisation step, `EnableGpkgMode` is needed as the geometry data and metadata is stored a bit different than with a classic Spatialite file. So, the initialisation can be done e.g. like this:

```
SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite');
SELECT EnableGpkgMode();
```

After running this, you can simply use (most) Spatialite functions. `CastAutomagic` was needed with spatialite 4.3, which was released 8 years ago and so is very outdated.